# Angular 2 - test for change in route params

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-routing, angular2-testing, angular2-observables

I have a component in angular 2 which responds to changes in the route parameters (the component doesn't reload from scratch because we're not moving out of the main route. Here's the component code:

```
export class MyComponent{
    ngOnInit() {
        this._routeInfo.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
            if (params['area']){
                this._pageToShow =params['area'];
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This works a treat and `_pageToShow` is set appropriate on navigation.

I'm trying to test the behaviour on a change to the route (so a second trigger of the observable but it's refusing to work for me.) Here's my attempt:

```
it('sets PageToShow to new area if params.area is changed', fakeAsync(() => {
    let routes : Params[] = [{ 'area': "Terry" }];
    TestBed.overrideComponent(MyComponent, {
        set: {
            providers: [{ provide: ActivatedRoute,
                useValue: { 'params': Observable.from(routes)}}]
        }
    });

    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    let comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    let route: ActivatedRoute = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ActivatedRoute);
    comp.ngOnInit();

    expect(comp.PageToShow).toBe("Terry");
    routes.splice(2,0,{ 'area': "Billy" });

    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(comp.PageToShow).toBe("Billy");
}));
```

But this throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` exception when I run it. If I run it without the `fixture.detectChanges();` line it fails as the second expectation fails.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Firstly, you should use a `Subject` instead of an `Observable`. The observable only gets subscribed to once. So it will only emit the first set of params. With a `Subject`, you can keep emitting items, and the single subscription will keep getting them.

```
let params: Subject<Params>;

beforeEach(() => {
  params = new Subject<Params>();
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: params }}
    ]
  })
})
```

Then in your test just emit new values with `params.next(newValue)`.

Secondly, you need to make sure to call `tick()`. This is how `fakeAsync` works. You control asynchronous task resolution. Since the observable as asychrounous, the moment we sent the event, it will not get to the subscriber synchronously. So we need to force synchronous behavior with `tick()`

Here is a complete test (`Subject` is imported from `'rxjs/Subject'`)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test',
  template: `
  `
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  _pageToShow: string;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      if (params['area']) {
        this._pageToShow = params['area'];
      }
    });
  }
}

describe('TestComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;
  let component: TestComponent;
  let params: Subject<Params>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    params = new Subject<Params>();
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TestComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: { params: params } }
      ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should change on route param change', fakeAsync(() => {
    // this calls ngOnInit and we subscribe
    fixture.detectChanges();

    params.next({ 'area': 'Terry' });

    // tick to make sure the async observable resolves
    tick();

    expect(component._pageToShow).toBe('Terry');

    params.next({ 'area': 'Billy' });
    tick();

    expect(component._pageToShow).toBe('Billy');
  }));
});
```

Comment: Make sure to scroll down in this solution for the inclusion on the `tick()` function! I completely missed that the first time. Thanks for the solution, this worked for me :)

Comment: I've been able to use this approach for `fragment` also for internal links: `fragment = new Subject<string>();`, which is appropriate for hiding/showing tab content, for example.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer to get route params and data from ActivatedRouteSnapshot like this `this.route.snapshot.params['type']`

If you use the same way, you can test it like this

1) In your test providers

```
{provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {snapshot: { params: { type: '' } }}}
```

2) in your test spec

```
it('should...', () => {
   component.route.snapshot.params['type'] = 'test';
   fixture.detectChanges();
   // ...
});
```

Comment: Cool, but take care of setting the default value in the first 'it' too, if the params used in more 'it', because the order of the tests is not fix at running. And it works only if the router is not private.

Comment: should be the accepted answer, no need to create your own subjects like the above answer