# how to write test case for activated route parameters angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

My application uses angular2 framework

I am trying to write test cases

it would be help full if anyone explain how to write test case for activated 
route parameters

here is the code  where i get id from the url

```
constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private authService: AuthService) {

    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.iId = params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
    });
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Testing a component, which depends on a route param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385851/testing-a-component-which-depends-on-a-route-param)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and solved it like this:

[Testing a component, which depends on a route param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385851/testing-a-component-which-depends-on-a-route-param)

Maybe it helps you!

Comment: this should be a comment. Link only answers tend to get downvoted and deleted.